# Double lines appearing at the border of tikz matrix table cells

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tikz-matrix

I have a piece of latex code:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\definecolor{arbitrary}{rgb}{0.9,1,1}

\begin{document}

    \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
    \pgfsetlayers{background,main}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes,nodes={minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1cm,draw,very thin},draw,inner sep=0]
    {   |[fill=arbitrary]|\quad & \verb|\definecolor{arbitrary}{rgb}{0.9,1,1}| & \#ABCDEF \\
         |[fill=arbitrary]|\quad & \verb|\definecolor{arbitrary}{rgb}{0.9,1,1}| & \#ABCDEF \\
    };
%   \draw[thick,violet] (magic-2-1.east) to[out=180,in=270,looseness=0.5] (magic-2-1.north) to[out=270,in=0,looseness=0.5] (magic-2-1.west) to[out=0,in=90,looseness=0.5] (magic-2-1.south) to[out=90,in=180,looseness=0.5] (magic-2-1.east);
%   \draw[rounded corners=2pt,densely dashed,green!50!gray] ($(magic-1-2.center)+(-0.15,-0.25)$) rectangle ($(magic-1-3.center)+(0.15,0.25)$);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How can I avoid the double lines appearing in the bottom of columns 2 and 3, and top of 1st column?

Here is the sample image:
[image]

I need only single line border for each cell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\definecolor{arbitrary}{rgb}{0.9,1,1}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes,
                 nodes={draw, very thin,
                        minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, 
                        inner sep=2mm, anchor=center}, % <--- added
                 inner sep=0pt, draw
                 ]
{   
|[fill=arbitrary]|
    & \verb|\definecolor{arbitrary}{rgb}{0.9,1,1}| & \#ABCDEF \\
|[fill=arbitrary]|
    & \verb|\definecolor{arbitrary}{rgb}{0.9,1,1}| & \#ABCDEF \\
};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the case, that all cells in the first column have the same color background, than you can write your matrix as follows:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
                matrix}

\definecolor{arbitrary}{rgb}{0.9,1,1}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (magic) [matrix of nodes,
                 nodes in empty cells,   
                 nodes={draw, very thin,
                        minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, 
                        inner sep=2mm, anchor=center},
                 column 1/.style = {nodes={fill=arbitrary}},
                 inner sep=0pt, draw
                 ]
{   
    & \verb|\definecolor{arbitrary}{rgb}{0.9,1,1}| & \#ABCDEF \\
    & \verb|\definecolor{arbitrary}{rgb}{0.9,1,1}| & \#ABCDEF \\
};
\draw[rounded corners=2pt,densely dashed,green!50!gray]
    ($(magic-1-2.center)+(-0.15,-0.25)$) rectangle ($(magic-1-3.center)+(0.15,0.25)$);
\draw[thick,violet]     (magic-2-1.east) 
            to[out=180,in=270,looseness=0.5] (magic-2-1.north)
            to[out=270,in=0,  looseness=0.5] (magic-2-1.west)
            to[out=0, in=90,  looseness=0.5] (magic-2-1.south)
            to[out=90,in=180, looseness=0.5] (magic-2-1.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have learnt that a table with different column width can be drawn with matrix of TikZ